# How do i add multiple custom columns in material-react-table? This code only adds one column named Action, i want to add more

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

const options = {
search: true,
download: true,
print: true,
viewColumns: true,
filter: true,
filterType: "dropdown",
elevation: 0,
responsive: "standard",
tableBodyHeight: "450px",
tableBodyMaxHeight: "",
selectableRows: 'none',

```
enableRowActions: 'true',
positionActionsColumn: 'last',

displayColumnDefOptions: {
  'mrt-row-actions': {
    header: 'Change Account Settings', //change header text
    size: 200, //make actions column wider
  },
},

renderRowActions: ({ row }) => (
  <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
    {row.original.role_id == 1 ? <div>Super Admin</div> : row.original.role_id == 2 ? <div>Admin</div> : <div>Agent</div>}
    <EnableDisableComp data={tranformToArray(row.original)} columns={columns} />
    <Edit size={16} className="text-theme mx-3" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "openModal", payload: <EditForm data={tranformToArray(row.original)} columns={columns} /> })} />
  </div>
),



renderTopToolbarCustomActions: () => {
  return (<Customtoolbar content={<AddForm />} />)
}
```

};

renderRowActions: ({ row }) => (

{row.original.role_id == 1 ? Super Admin : row.original.role_id == 2 ? Admin : Agent}

<Edit size={16} className="text-theme mx-3" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "openModal", payload:  })} />

),